# What is the purpose of testComplete() command in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I can't find out what's the purpose of the `testComplete()` function in Selenium, and what the difference between `testComplete()` and `end()` is.

It definitely doesn't help that there is another test framework called TestComplete...search results about it are completely polluted :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no more testComplete() function in selenium. It existed in old version of selenium-rc protocol, but was removed after protocol update in 2006. See source code history, revision 931:
http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/selenium-rc/trunk/clients/java/src/main/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.java#btrunk

I don't remember if end() function ever existed in selenium. Instead, there are functions close() - to close browser window, and stop() - to finish remote session.